# Getting the number of dimensions of a std::vector/std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Let's say I want a `class/struct` type, inheriting from `integral_constant<size_t, N>` where N is the dimension and the dimension is achieved as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct dimension;

template<class T>
struct dimension<vector<T>> : integral_constant<size_t, 1> {};

template<class T>
struct dimension<vector<vector<T>>> : integral_constant<size_t, 2> {};
```

And then

```
cout << dimension<vector<int>>::value;         // 1
cout << dimension<vector<vector<int>>>::value; // 2
```

But obviously this is not perfect, as the number of dimensions can be a infinite (in theory). Is there a way to achieve a generic solution to this?

Suggestion: I went in this direction, but no further:

```
template<class T, class... Tn>
struct dimension<vector<Tn...>> : integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Tn)> {};
```

Since `std::vector` has other template parameters this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for a `std::vector` (note that the template parameter list of a `std::vector` is longer than 1):

```
template<typename T>
struct dimension { static constexpr std::size_t value = 0; };

template<typename T, typename... V>
struct dimension<std::vector<T, V...>>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1 + dimension<T>::value;
};
```

This works instead for a `std::array`:

```
template<typename>
struct dimension { static constexpr std::size_t value = 0; };

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct dimension<std::array<T, N>>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1 + dimension<T>::value;
};
```

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct dimension { static constexpr std::size_t value = 0; };

template<typename T, typename... V>
struct dimension<std::vector<T, V...>>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1 + dimension<T>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << dimension<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That was my though as well. It would have to be constrained.

Comment: @T.C. Right. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

A bit hard to define "what's a container". The below checks for `value_type`, `iterator`, and `const_iterator` nested typedefs. Tweak the `void_t` check as you want. (For instance, if you want only things that can be subscripted to be recognized as containers, then add `decltype(std::declval<T&>()[0])` to the list.)

Note that `dimension_impl`'s specialization calls `dimension`. this allows you to specialize `dimension` for container-like things you don't want to be treated as a container (`std::string` comes to mind).

```
template<class T> struct dimension;

namespace details {    
    template<class T, class = void>
    struct dimension_impl {
        static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct dimension_impl<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type,
                                         typename T::iterator,
                                         typename T::const_iterator>> {
        static constexpr std::size_t value = 1 + dimension<typename T::value_type>::value;
    };
}

template<class T>
struct dimension : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
                                          details::dimension_impl<T>::value> {};
```

Comment: This way you'd be reporting that `std::vector<std::list<int>>` has a dimension of 2.

Comment: @skypjack Which is fine with me. A `list<int>` is a container. If someone only wants to recognize exactly `std::vector` and `std::array`, they have your answer. (I question the usefulness of doing so, considering that there are myriad `vector`-like containers out there.)

Comment: I got the question as - _I want to find the dimension of a chain of vectors or a chain of arrays_. You'd allow chains that contain both types (and all the other containers as well). Is it what the OP wants?

Comment: I guess I worded my question wrongly as I was trying to be very specific. Both answers are of great value to my original application, which is vastly different from this artificially emulated example of vectors.